# html element changes its position while giving position relative attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, position

i have a wordpress website [enter link description here](http://molugu.com/yantraev)

i have created a mobile menu using a plugin, as the mobile menu was sticky i wanted to remove the sticky property, so i did the following css to it:

```css
.mobmenu{position:relative !important; }
```

now the sticky property is gone, but the menu has changed its position from header and went a long way down to the footer, can anyone please tell me how can i make the element not change the positon while using relative property, i mean i want the element to be in its original position as before.

Comment: Did you mean `position: absolute` instead?

Comment: @SebastianSimon absolute is not working, so i used relative

Comment: Try to use position:absolute !important; top:0

Comment: @MuthulakshmiM used it, still its sticky

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the propery `position:relative` to the parent of that element, and to that element set the propery `position:abosulte`. The way this works it that the child element `.mobmenu` will be placed relatively to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the theme you're using, normally you can go into Wordpress Menu > Appearance > Customize and search for de Header configuration. There you can set if you want the menubar is fixed or not

Comment: the menu is coming from a plugin

Comment: what plugin are you using?

Comment: WP Mobile Menu – The Mobile-Friendly Responsive

Answer (score 0):

Try to go in your WordPress Dashboard under “Appearance-> Customize-> Additional CSS” and paste this CSS code:

```
header.site-header {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: this doesnt make any change